# Store cell values to Object

Tags: automation, apache-poi

I'm currently new to TestNG using java. I'm trying to read the values from an excel using poi apache 4.0

```java
public static void read2dRowExcelFile2(String filePath) throws IOException {

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("PerLocation");

        Object[][] tableArr = new String[sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1][];
        int arrNo1 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);              
            int arrNo2 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                String cellValue = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(acellValue);
                //tableArr[arrNo1][arrNo2] = cellValue;
                System.out.println("test");
                arrNo2++;
            }
            
            arrNo1++;
        }
        
        wb.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code above displays the values on the console. My goal is to store those values to an Object. Something like [{London, Blue},{Tokyo,Yellow},{Manila,Red}] so I can pass them to a dataProvider

If I run the code above, it displays :
London
BLue
Tokyo
Yellow
Manila
Red

But If i uncomment this line :

```
//tableArr[arrNo1][arrNo2] = cellValue;
```

The output is only :
London

03-08-19 : After I enabled stacktrace, it says : java.lang.NullPointerException
which pertains to this code :

```
tableArr[arrNo1][arrNo2] = cellValue;
```

Comment: There is an exception thrown which you are silently ignoring. Put `e.printStackTrace();` into your `catch` block and you will see.

Comment: Hi. Thanks @AxelRichter. I didn't notice that, thanks for this tip.. if you don't mind? May I ask if i'm doing the right thing on storing values to an Object : `code`tableArr[arrNo1][arrNo2] = cellValue;`code` after i enable the stacktrace, its says java.lang.NullPointerException pertaining to this line. I tried printing out my variables, and it has values. sorry to bother.

Comment: After `Object[][] tableArr = new String[sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1][];` what do you think arre the dimensions of your `Object[][] tableArr `?

Comment: @AxelRichter. I think I got it now, the null refers to the second dimension of the object. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. And because of the static behavior of array dimensions, you should better using a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) instead. A `List<List<String>> tableList` for example.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
Object[][] tableArr = new String[sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1][];
```

At the time of initialization of array, your are setting size of first dimension but not the second . You need to initialize array for second dimension before you access it.

Refer below example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //read rows size
        int numOfRows = 3;
        String[][] tableArr = new String[numOfRows][];

        for (int row = 0; row <3; row++) {
            //read columns size
            int numOfColsInRow = 3;
            tableArr[row]=new String[numOfColsInRow];              
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                String cellValue = "cell-" + row+""+col;//read cell value
                tableArr[row][col] = cellValue;
            }
        }

        for(String[] row: tableArr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
```

Running above code with generate expected output:

```
[cell-00, cell-01, cell-02]
[cell-10, cell-11, cell-12]
[cell-20, cell-21, cell-22]
```

To reproduce your problem you can try commenting line which initialize array for second dimension in the code and you will see `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`
.

```
        //tableArr[row]=new String[numOfColsInRow];
```

To avoid all such issues you also can check if any exiting [TestNG data-provider extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension) satisfies your need.